# Remove sort from hit result in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If ElasticSearch query, contain any sort, example:

```
{
    query : { term : { field : "something" } },
    sort : [ { name : { order : "asc" } } ],
    fields : []
}
```

Even with `fields : []` results contain special field "sort", with array of values, calculated values, expression result etc...

Is this possible to disable this additional field? ElasticSearch 2.3.*

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use `filter_path` option in url for more details you can follow below POST of my blog

http://www.kpblogs.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-with-mysql-using-logstash/

Comment: This field is still calculated right, only filtered before response?

Comment: This link doesn't work any more. The answer should include more details.